# How to install 32 bit jdk on 64 bit?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, java

Is there any way to install 32 bit JDK on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04? I installed 64 bit versions of java (jdk-jdk6) on Ubuntu, but when I do those steps (I have applied for 64 bit versions of java) to 32 bit JDK and type

```
java -version
```

it gives me a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: Problem is solved. Just installed ia23-libs:
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: There is no `jdk-jdk6` package. Assuming `openjdk-6-jdk` was meant, which has architecture `amd64` if installed from the official repositories. What is meant by "I have applied for 64 bit versions of java"?

Answer (score 4):

OP posted:

Problem is solved. Just installed `ia23-libs`:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```